# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

Tags: python-3.x

I came across a code https://github.com/scorpionhiccup/StockPricePrediction looked pretty interesting. But when I tried to execute the program (regression_models.py ie https://github.com/scorpionhiccup/StockPricePrediction/blob/master/scripts/Algorithms/regression_models.py ) I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'
```

The section of code generating this error is

```
for pred in predicted_values:
        mean_squared_errors.append(mean_squared_error(test[output].as_matrix(), \
         pred.as_matrix()))
        r2_scores.append(r2_score(test[output].as_matrix(), pred.as_matrix()))
```

I am new to python and I tried alot but didn't get the solution. Any help is appreciated. 
I am using ActivePython 3.6.0.3600 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 23 2017, 20:01:14) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 0):

`as_matrix()` is an old, deprecated method of `pandas.DataFrame`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html

You evidently are passing a NumPy array where the code expected a DataFrame.  But that's fine, because all `as_matrix()` does is convert a DataFrame to an array.  So try just removing one or more of the `.as_matrix()` calls (I can't tell which one is the problem, or maybe all of them are).

Comment: If i remove all .as_matrix() calls or if i remove .as_matrix() call from second parameter pred then i'm getting error File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\regression.py", line 238, in mean_squared_error
    y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\regression.py", line 87, in _check_reg_targets
    "({0}!={1})".format(y_true.shape[1], y_pred.shape[1]))
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=2193)